# How to control remote rtsp server using playbin

Tags: android, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm working with gstreamer and I can play RTSP stream using below code:

```
data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("playbin", &error);
```

//avi.sdp is a video file that in  server

```
g_object_set(data->pipeline, "uri", "rtsp://192.168.1.1/avi.sdp", NULL);
```

When stream playing , i can pause it,

```
gst_element_set_state (data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
```

then when I set playing again, it restart playing!

```
gst_element_set_state (data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

is playbin support rtsp stream play & pause? if not, how can I implement this?

Comment: what happens whan you run it in `gst-play-1.0 rtsp://...` ? you shall be able to pause with space, it works for me. btw is this really RTSP? SDP is used for RTP or am I wrong?

Comment: @otopolsky, it unable to pause with space when i test `gst-play-1.0 rtsp://...`  on ubuntu. Yes, it is RTSP and use mjpeg format.

Comment: ok sorry I realized that pausing rtsp from gst-play is working on gstreamer 1.6 (not sure since when). In earlier versions pausing is not working for me. I was testing on `rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov` from [here](http://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html). Can you test it on that stream?